# PHP echoing without masquerading

Tags: php, echo

I've heard about a possibility to echo a string (e.g. HTML) without masquerading every quote. As I remember, it looks something like this:

```
<?php
ECHO SOME_NAME 

<div style="background-color: green;">The quotes here doesn't have to be masqueraded</div>

SOME_NAME
?>
```

But I don't know how it actually really works. Can you help me?

Greez, Florian

Comment: what do you man by `masquerade`?

Comment: @ThorpeObazee I meant "masking", but at this time my english was pretty poor :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably mean the [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax (read it! it has some unexpected things like the END marker having to be the **only** thing on the line - i.e. no indentation before or comments/code after the semicolon):

```
echo <<<END
your stuff with " and ' here
END;
```

If you can use PHP 5.3 and don't want variables to be replaced inside the string, go with the [oewdoc](http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) syntax:

```
echo <<<'END'
your stuff with " and ' and $not_parsed here
END;
```

Answer (score 4):

no need to use heredoc to echo HTML
PHP has a way better way.

```
?>
<div style="background-color: green;">
 The quotes here doesn't have to be masqueraded
</div>
<?php
```

an HTML becomes pure HTML this way, with all advantages of syntax highlighting, code hinting etc.
there is not a single reason to use heredoc to echo HTML blocks.

Comment: yap true +1 that is how i do too.

Comment: I disagree. Heredoc is useful because it does some parsing (for example, \x00 will output a NUL byte, and $someVariable will be parsed too). Also, this method does not work to initialize class constants and static values with large chunks of text.

Comment: @Artefact2 for echoing, silly. not for class constants definition, but for echoing, as it's stated in the OP. and, to let you know, if you have constants in your class that contains HTML, you're in deep trouble. Start learning templates, dude.

Comment: I agree. That's why I said "large chunks of text", and they can contain ' or " characters too.

Comment: @Artefact2 in fact, it is useful to fill some text messages like email body. But it has no use for serving browser's requests - it's template's job.

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about [PHP heredoc syntax](http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-heredoc-syntax.html)

**Example:**

```
  <?php
  $name = "Max";
  $str = <<<DEMO
  Hello $name! <br/>
  This is a
  demo message
  with heredoc.
DEMO;

  echo $str;
  ?>
```

**Important:**

> It is very important to note that the
>   line with the closing identifier must
>   contain no other characters, except
>   possibly a semicolon (;). That means
>   especially that the identifier may not
>   be indented, and there may not be any
>   spaces or tabs before or after the
>   semicolon. It's also important to
>   realize that the first character
>   before the closing identifier must be
>   a newline as defined by the local
>   operating system. This is \n on UNIX
>   systems, including Mac OS X. The
>   closing delimiter (possibly followed
>   by a semicolon) must also be followed
>   by a newline.

Answer (score 1):

You might also be interested in exploring the [Nowdoc syntax, available since PHP 5.3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc)